# Active Directory Querying with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am building a report on our active directory groups and am having a hard time when it comes to different forests.

We have groups from forestA with users inside from forestB.  I was able to pull those groups using Quest AD:

```
 $GroupUsers = Get-QADGroupMember $GroupName -Type 'user' -Indirect
```

The only problem is that even though the users inside are from forest B, they come up showing they are from forestA. They do exist in both forests, don't know if that's a problem.

Any clue on why this happens?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use Powershell AD module bundled with Windows? Maybe that one doesn't have these issues. Just in case.

Comment: I tried but with the windows module I couldn't even find the group of a different forest.

Answer (score 1):

There is `-Server` parameter of `Get-ADGroupMember` cmdlet where you may specify domain controller from another domain/forest. Something like:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName -Server DC.AnotherDomain.com
```

Comment: Whenever I use this parameter I get the same error: Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, o
r it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running.
Which is funny because I can connect using the QAD-getmember

Comment: Hm, you need to identify domain controller in that other forest. I don't see any other way for Quest to get that info, except from domain services in another forest. Try running this `Get-ADDomainController -DomainName AnotherDomain.com` and then query server which is returned.

Comment: all I get is this: Domain      : ttbb.bb-group.com
Forest      : bb-group.com
HostName    : {ttao10p00053.ttbb.bb-group.com}
IPv4Address : 199.xx.xx.28
IPv6Address : 
Name        : TTAO10P00053
Site        : TAO01

But querying with this information doesn't work to

Answer (score 0):

you can query forest for domains or all global catalogs: get-adforest  (properties GlobalCatalogs,Domains) - I often did something like this:
I pulled the list of all SIDs in the group then checked which one belongs to my domain/forest, the rest was searched in external forest.